# No overload for matches delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have this method:

```
public static void InsertPageNumbering(object sender, CreateAreaEventArgs e, BaseOracleUtils OraCon)
{
   PCK.SetData(OraCon);
}
```

How to assign it to event:

```
 compositeLink.CreateMarginalFooterArea += BaseSettingsInit.InsertPageNumbering;
```

CreateMarginalFooterArea have this parameters:

```
 public delegate void CreateAreaEventHandler(object sender, CreateAreaEventArgs e);
```

Is any option assign method (with keeping OraCon parameter)?

Comment: This can't work in C# because method and delegate don't have same parameters

Comment: Yes, i understand this think, but is anyone option to set variable into method InsertPageNumbering or maybe you have other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler says it all.

**CS0123 - No overload for InsertPageNumbering matches delegate CreateAreaEventHandler.**

If you were able to assign the method to the event what should happen during invocation of the event? What value of `BaseOracleUtils` should be passed as the `OraCon` parameter?

Unfortunately you are not able to provide default for the last parameter either. The only solution I see is to either extend the delegate to accept one more parameter.

Or create a wrapper around your `InsertPageNumbering` method such as

```
public static void InsertPageNumberingWrapper(object sender, CreateAreaEventArgs e)
{
    InsertPageNumbering(sender, e, GetBaseOracleUtils());
}
```

which would provide some reasonable value as the last parameter to it. And then add this wrapper to the event. `GetBaseOracleUtils()` could pull the value out of somewhere (I have no idea what are you trying to solve and where should the value come from).

Comment: Your example helped me to solve my problem, thanks soo much.

Comment: @Archi.Moore Glad I could help.